# Error Code 34 from telegram.org. Odd versus Even msg_seqnos

Tags: python, telegram

I am receiving an [error_code](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages_about_messages) 34 from the server, which means: "*an even msg_seqno expected (irrelevant message), but odd received*"

It is my understanding a `msg_seqno` sent to the server is always odd. Perhaps this is only for content type messages, please comment on this if you can.

Even if that is the case I'm confused by the error. Which of the following outgoing `msg_seqnos` (msg1, msg2, msg3) should be odd and which should be even?

## calling method invokeWithLayer

```
('method_call: ', 'invokeWithLayer', {'query': '\xe9myi\xc0\t\x00\x00\x11Unknown UserAgent\x00\x00\x10Unknown Platform\x00\x00\x00\x030.7\x05en-US\x00\x00&0\xb3\x1f', 'layer': 55})
```

## client detects msgs_ack is needed

...create msgs_ack back to the server

## the invokeWithLayer msg is serialized

msg1:

```
create_msg_data_type - seqno: 3
create_msg_data_type - message_id: 6342878133672398848
```

## the msgs_ack msg is serialized

msg2:

```
create_msg_data_type - seqno: 5
create_msg_data_type - message_id: 6342878137971661824
```

## ...creating MessageContainer from above msgs

msg3:

```
create_tcp_packet - encrypting data...:
create_msg_data_type - seqno: 7
create_msg_data_type - message_id: 6342878142266629120
```

## sending the MessageContainer

```
--> send_message: sending..message_id: 6342878142266629120
```

## error message returned

```
<-- ('TL deserialize: x = ', {u'bad_msg_seqno': 7, u'bad_msg_id': 6342878142266629120L, u'error_code': 34})
```

Comment: have you been able to resolve the message_ack issues?

Comment: Nope. This question is part of that process. I'm sending the acks but getting the above error.

Comment: If you have an answer I would love to hear it!

Comment: Would need to go step by step over your current msg_ack implemetation